# geometric interpretation of analytical hahn-banach theorem

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

[image]

[image]
[image]

I understand this interpretation.
But how can I see this in example?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what kind of example you want?

Comment: any example by which i see this interpretation.
say,if we work in three dimensions what would be the situation.
How would the hyperplane extend to a largeer hyperplane at the same distance?

Comment: Please don't close. This is a valid and quite important question for understanding the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In finite dimensions the picture is quite clear, because we have the inner product.

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, each linear functional is specified by taking the inner product with a vector $x = (x_1,x_2)$. The equation
$$
\langle x,y\rangle = 1
$$
specifies a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ at distance $1/\Vert x\Vert$ from $0$. (This is easy geometry.)

Regarding $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, we can extend $x$ to the linear functional $x = (x_1,x_2,0)$, which obviously has the same norm as $(x_1,x_2)$. The equation
$$
\langle x, y\rangle = 1
$$
(keeping in mind this is the inner product in $\mathbb{R}^3$ now) specifies a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and clearly it contains the line $L$ in $\mathbb{R}^2 \subset\mathbb{R}^3$ from earlier and is the same distance from the origin.